# Cannot connect Npgsql to Postgres running on Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, docker, entity-framework

I have Postgres running on Docker, I'm trying to update the DB with EntityFramework and I get an error in the Package Manager Console: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432. The postgres was created directly in Docker Desktop app.

```
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|208_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:5432
```

Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnection")));
```

Connection string in appsettings.json

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbConnection": "Host=172.17.0.2; Port=5432; Database=MyNewDb; Username=postgres; Password=postgrespw;"
  }
```

I checked on what ip and port the container is running:

```bash
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                           NAMES
f9b7485b6473   dpage/pgadmin4    "/entrypoint.sh"         59 minutes ago      Up 58 minutes      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   pgadmin4
f1422d67616e   postgres:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:49153->5432/tcp         postgres-O7pV

❯ docker inspect f1422 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",

❯ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
5a77b8e238bc   bridge    bridge    local
aae4971464e6   host      host      local
59c3a23f98d4   none      null      local
```

Comment: By default, Docker's DHCP will not publish any ports to be accessed from outside of the docker instance. If your app is hosted/running within the docker environment it should be able to reach the PostgreSQL instance. To access it externally to test you should be able to open the port by launching the container with "-p 5432" .